# Price feed of multiple coins in a single GET request

Tags: tokens, oracles, external-api, coinbase, chainlink

I have used Chainlink oracle to get the price feed of a single coin. But I want to fetch the latest price of 100s of coins from the smart contract using oracle. Is it possible to get the price of multiple coins in a single GET request? If not, what is the best way to deal with it?
(Surely one request/coin costs a lot of gas and transaction time)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as "multi-word answers" and it's currently in development.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any hack or a partial solution for the problem?

Comment: You can either do multiple calls, or just grab the data from the data feeds: https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price